# Запись в txt значения переменной

Tags: python

```
links = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8").read().split('\n')

for i in links:
    a = i.split(';')
    a = a[-1]
#   print(a)
```

Как записать в txt файл построчно значения переменной '**a**'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть файл на запись и:

```
links = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8").read().split('\n')

with open('new.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for i in links:
        a = i.split(';')
        a = a[-1]
        f.write(a + "\n")
```